What is the origin of the names "forward" and "quasi-resonant" converters?
I'm curious about the names of some types of converters, such as forward and quasi-resonant converters. Why are they called forward and quasi-resonant?
Regarding quasi-resonant, I found an explanation here. Does a hybrid between PWM and resonant converters mean that it has both square wave and sine waveform, while in true resonant converters, there is only a sine wave (no square wave)?



What is the origin of the names "forward" and "quasi-resonant"
converters?

Let's start with the word Quasi. This source describes it as: -

having some resemblance usually by possession of certain attributes

So, a quasi resonant converter possesses attributes that can be described as being resonant or related to a resonant circuit. And that's exactly what they are. They use PWM or phase shifted PWM (to keep resonant energy flowing) and a tuned circuit to overcome problems such as leakage inductance in a transformer restricting the performance.

while in true resonant converters, there is only a sine wave (no
square wave)?

Correct.

I'm curious about the names of some types of converters, such as
forward

A flyback converter transfers energy to its output during the reverse phase of the primary but, a forward converter will transfer energy directly on the forward conduction of the primary and, by inference it can also convey energy on the reverse conduction of the primary. But, it's called a forward converter to distinguish it from a flyback converter.
